# Swift Modal Self Becomes Nil

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, modal-dialog

I have a UIViewController that when a button is pressed I open another View from a segue.  When it opens everything is fine and all the functionality works.  However, if I close the modal and then try to re-open it, *self* is nil.

This is the code I'm using to open the Modal:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Search", sender: self)
```

My modal has a segue defined as:

Present Modally

Over Full Screen

I then have a close button within the modal that does the following:

```
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Finally, when I try to open the modal again with the "Search" segue *self* within the modal's UIViewController is *nil*.

Therefore, when I try to use it, I get this message:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I assume I'm keeping a reference to the UIViewController somewhere, I just don't know how.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: So you tap the button and it pops up the modal and then you dismiss the modal and tap the same button again and it gives you an error? This should work fine based on the code you show above, you should double check some of the other code in your app. Possibly try setting "sender: nil" in your performSegue.

Comment: @TravisM. Exactly.  So I tap the button that does the performSegue.  It opens the Modal.  I close the Modal.  Reopen it, and if I try to use 'self' within the modal (which I do, as I use a list for a tableview within the modal), it crashes as 'self' is now nil.  I did try setting sender: nil within the performSegue as per your suggestion, although no change.

Answer (score 0):

Okay,

So it turns out the code that I omitted was causing the issue.  My apologies, I just did not think it would be caused by it, as it was working in all other use cases.

I am using Socket.IO to communicate with a NodeJS server in real time.

Within a socket.on:

```
var user = User.sharedInstance

user.socket!.on("search") {[weak self]data, ack in

        var json = JSON(data!)

        self.songs.removeAll() // <- Caused the error.

...
```

So it turns out that the `[weak self]` causes the self to be nil if it was already set before.  So the first time I would open the Modal, the `user.socket!.on('search') {[weak self] data, ack in ...` worked fine, although the second time, when I referred to `self` within the socket call again, it caused it to be null.

Thank you!